# Should the dimension of WORK array on xGEHRD and xHSEQR routines be equal on eigenvalue calculation?

Tags: c, linear-algebra, lapack, eigenvalue, atlas

I'm calculating the eigenvalues of a dense non symmetric matrix A. For that purpose I use [xGEHRD](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapack-3.1.1/html/sgehrd.f.html) and [xHSEQR](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapack-3.1.1/html/shseqr.f.html) Lapack routines in order to calculate first the upper Hessenberg form of A and then to calculate the only the eigenvalues of the obtained matrix.

Both routines require the parameter LWORK and both provide a mechanism to calculate its optimal value. I believe that this parameter is related to an internal blocking of buffer technique, but I don't know how it is determined.

Using the query mechanism to obtain the optimal value of LWORK the workflow should be like:

```
int LWORK = -1;
float* OPT_LWORK = (float*) malloc( sizeof(float));

sgehrd_ (..., OPT_LWORK ,&LWORK, ...) // query optimal value for sgehrd

LWORK = (int) OPT_WORK
float* WORK = (float*) malloc( (int) sizeof(float) * LWORK );

sgehrd_ (..., WORK ,&LWORK, ...) // calculate Hessenberg

int LWORK = -1;
shseqr_ (..., OPT_LWORK ,&LWORK, ...) // query optimal value for shseqr

LWORK = (int) OPT_WORK
float* WORK = // possibly realloc with the new LWORK value

shseqr_ (..., WORK ,&LWORK, ...) // finally obtain eigenvalues
```

I've done some testing, obtaining always the same optimal values for the dimension of WORK array. If the values were the same, I could simplify my code a lot (no need for realloc and only one call to determine the value of LWORK, less error checking...).

My question is, **for the same matrix and the same values of ILO and IHI, can I assume that the values   are going to be equal the both routines?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [sgehrd.f](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-3.1.1-html/sgehrd.f.html), it seems that the optimal size of `WORK` for routine `sgehrd()` is `N*NB`, where `NB` is

```
NB = MIN( NBMAX, ILAENV( 1, 'SGEHRD', ' ', N, ILO, IHI, -1 ) )
```

where `NBMAX=64`. Hence, the optimal `LWORK` depends on `N`, `ILO` and `IHI`.

Looking at [shseqr.f](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapack-3.1.1/html/shseqr.f.html), the computation of the optimal length `LWORK` is more complex : the routine `slaqr0()` is called... But the documentation in the file states :

> If LWORK = -1, then SHSEQR does a workspace query.
>     In this case, SHSEQR checks the input parameters and
>     estimates ***the optimal workspace size for the given
>     values of N, ILO and IHI***.  The estimate is returned
>     in WORK(1).  No error message related to LWORK is
>     issued by XERBLA.  Neither H nor Z are accessed.

The optimal length of `WORK` may be different for `sgehrd()` and `shseqr()`. Here is an example :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern void sgehrd_(int *n,int* ilo, int* ihi, float* a,int* lda,float* tau,float* work, int* lwork,int* info);

extern void shseqr_(char* job,char* compz,int *n,int* ilo, int* ihi,float* h,int* ldh,float* wr,float* wi,float* z,int* ldz,float* work, int* lwork,int* info);

int main()
{
    int n=10;
    int ilo=n;
    int ihi=n;
    float* a=malloc(sizeof(float)*n*n);
    int lda=n;
    float* tau=malloc(sizeof(float)*(n-1));
    int info;

    char job='S';
    char compz='I';
    float* h=malloc(sizeof(float)*n*n);
    int ldh=n;
    float* wr=malloc(sizeof(float)*(n));
    float* wi=malloc(sizeof(float)*(n));
    float* z=malloc(sizeof(float)*n*n);
    int ldz=n;

    int LWORK = -1;
    float* OPT_LWORK =(float*) malloc( sizeof(float));

    sgehrd_ (&n,&ilo, &ihi, a,&lda,tau,OPT_LWORK ,&LWORK,&info); // query optimal value for sgehrd
    if(info!=0){printf("sgehrd lwork=-1 : failed\n");}

    LWORK = (int) OPT_LWORK[0];
    printf("sgehrd,length of optimal work : %d \n",LWORK);

    float* WORK = (float*) malloc( (int) sizeof(float) * LWORK );

    sgehrd_ (&n,&ilo, &ihi, a,&lda,tau,WORK ,&LWORK,&info);// calculate Hessenberg
    if(info!=0){printf("sgehrd execution : failed\n");}

    LWORK = -1;
    shseqr_ (&job,&compz,&n,&ilo, &ihi, h,&ldh, wr, wi,z,&ldz, OPT_LWORK ,&LWORK, &info); // query optimal value for shseqr
    if(info!=0){printf("shgeqr lwork=-1 : failed\n");}

    LWORK = (int) OPT_LWORK[0];
    printf("shseqr,length of optimal work : %d \n",LWORK);

    WORK = realloc(WORK,(int) sizeof(float) * LWORK );// possibly realloc with the new LWORK value

    shseqr_ (&job,&compz,&n,&ilo, &ihi, h,&ldh, wr, wi,z,&ldz, WORK ,&LWORK, &info);  // finally obtain eigenvalues
    if(info!=0){printf("shgeqr execution : failed\n");}

    free(OPT_LWORK);
    free(WORK);

    free(a);
    free(tau);
    free(h);
    free(wr);
    free(wi);
    free(z);

}
```

Compile by `gcc main.c -o main -llapack -lblas`

My output is :

```
sgehrd,length of optimal work : 320 
shseqr,length of optimal work : 10
```